# Best way to save 360 degree photos

Tags: database, 360-degrees, 360-virtual-reality, 360-panorama

I want to create a new site with 360 degree photos (a lot of them). What is the best way to save such photos?

Answer (score 1):

360 degree panoramic photos are made possible with an equirectangular image that is displayed via a JavaScript image viewer in a browser.

The 360 panorama exists as a single image file, normally a JPEG. Depending on your equipment, the equirectangular image might be output as a single JPEG (if it's a high-end panoramic camera) or more likely, you'll download series of photos and they'll be stitched together with software into the final equirectangular image.

They look warped in shape, for example:

[image: An equirectangular image]

Once you have the JPEG, you can upload it to your website and display it using a panoramic image viewer.